# Default AVCaptureDevice for front position is too "wide" on iPhone 11

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

Default `Camera.app` on iPhone 11 acts a little bit different when it comes to selfie camera. It now has a "zoom out" button, which kind of acts as switching to ultra-wide camera. Image below demonstrates the difference between zoom modes.

[image]

In my custom camera app, I'm trying to achieve the same "default zoom" camera, but `AVCaptureDevice`, for some reason, returns only the "ultra-wide angle" camera. I understand that there's only one frontal camera (not counting the `.builtInTrueDepthCamera`) in iPhone 11, so `Camera.app` probably manually zooms-in the image by default.

Is my guess correct? If my guess is correct, what is the best way to manually zoom-in `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`?

Comment: Could it be that the default is the `builtInTrueDepthCamera` (which has a tighter crop due to depth sensing) and the zoomed-out version is the `builtInWideAngleCamera`?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I tried to use `builtInTrueDepthCamera` but the result output was the same :(

Comment: Interesting... Then they probably just set the `videoZoomFactor` to something higher than `1.0` by default for the front camera.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the zoomed out front camera mode that you are describing (right screenshot) because for me it is default zoom. What settings did you use to get it? I have tried every combination and cannot find any docs explaining it.

Comment: @xinatanil Have you solved this? If you solved it, could you tell me?

Comment: @helloyako I didn't solve the issue, just left it as is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to implement the same function, and I finally found it.

When setting sessionPreset in Camera, you can implement it as above by setting it to AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo.

If you just set it up right away, it comes out as a zoomed-out image, and you can crop this part and use it in a 3:4 ratio. When you press the expansion button, it comes out as it is.

Comment: I was confused, you can just change the zoom factor and use it instead of crop.